# Title and event form input not posted and retrieve using Reactjs

Tags: reactjs

The Reactjs code below works excellently by posting and retrieving Users **newStatus** from a form input to and from an API.

Now I want to add two additional form form inputs **(newTitle and newEvent)**  as per code below

```
<input className="input-status" name="newTitle"

                    value={this.state.newTitle}
                    onChange={e => this.handleNewStatusChange(e)}
                    placeholder="your Title"
                  />

<input className="input-status" name="newEvent"

                    value={this.state.newEvent}
                    onChange={e => this.handleNewStatusChange(e)}
                    placeholder="Your Event Centre Name"
                  />
```

I have also implemented **newEvent** and **newTitle** variables in code where possible. My issue is that if type in the first form inputs (eg newStatus) it gets replicated or inserted in all other remaining two forms inputs as can be seen in the screenshot below.

And I believe that's why only the newStatus get posted and retrieved.

[image: screenshot]

I have commented out all newEvent and newTitle variables in code so readers can see where I am wrong.

Here is the code **profile.jsx**:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  isSignInPending,
  loadUserData,
  Person,
  getFile,
  putFile,
  lookupProfile
} from 'blockstack';
import Status from './Status.jsx';

const avatarFallbackImage = 'https://mysite/onename/avatar-placeholder.png';
const statusFileName = 'statuses.json'

export default class Profile extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      person: {
        name() {
          return 'Anonymous';
        },
        avatarUrl() {
          return avatarFallbackImage;
        },
      },
      username: "",
      newStatus: "",
      //newTitle: "",
     // newEvent: "",
      statuses: [],
      statusIndex: 0,
      isLoading: false
    };

    this.handleDelete = this.handleDelete.bind(this);
    this.isLocal = this.isLocal.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchData()
  }

  handleNewStatusChange(event) {
    this.setState({
      newStatus: event.target.value,
      //newTitle: event.target.value,
      //newEvent: event.target.value
    })
  }

  handleNewStatusSubmit(event) {
    this.saveNewStatus(
this.state.newStatus, 
//this.state.newTitle,
 //this.state.newEvent
)
    this.setState({
      newStatus: "",
      //newTitle: "",
      //newEvent: "",
    })
  }

  handleDelete(id) {
    const statuses = this.state.statuses.filter((status) => status.id !== id)
    const options = { encrypt: false }

    putFile(statusFileName, JSON.stringify(statuses), options)
      .then(() => {
        this.setState({
          statuses
        })
      })
  }

  saveNewStatus(statusText) {
    let statuses = this.state.statuses

    let status = {
      id: this.state.statusIndex++,
      text: statusText.trim(),
      //textTitle: statusText.trim(),
      //textEvent: statusText.trim(),
      created_at: Date.now()
    }

    statuses.unshift(status)
    const options = { encrypt: false }
    putFile(statusFileName, JSON.stringify(statuses), options)
      .then(() => {
        this.setState({
          statuses: statuses
        })
      })
  }

  fetchData() {
    if (this.isLocal()) {
      this.setState({ isLoading: true })
      const options = { decrypt: false, zoneFileLookupURL: 'https://myapi/v1/names/' }
      getFile(statusFileName, options)
        .then((file) => {
          var statuses = JSON.parse(file || '[]')
          this.setState({
            person: new Person(loadUserData().profile),
            username: loadUserData().username,
            statusIndex: statuses.length,
            statuses: statuses,
          })
        })
        .finally(() => {
          this.setState({ isLoading: false })
        })
    } else {
      const username = this.props.match.params.username
      this.setState({ isLoading: true })

      lookupProfile(username)
        .then((profile) => {
          this.setState({
            person: new Person(profile),
            username: username
          })
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log('could not resolve profile')
        })

      const options = { username: username, decrypt: false, zoneFileLookupURL: 'https://myapi/v1/names/'}

      getFile(statusFileName, options)
        .then((file) => {
          var statuses = JSON.parse(file || '[]')
          this.setState({
            statusIndex: statuses.length,
            statuses: statuses
          })
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log('could not fetch statuses')
        })
        .finally(() => {
          this.setState({ isLoading: false })
        })
    }
  }

  isLocal() {
    return this.props.match.params.username ? false : true
  }

  render() {
    const { handleSignOut } = this.props;
    const { person } = this.state;
    const { username } = this.state;

    return (
      !isSignInPending() && person ?
      <div className="container">
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col-md-offset-3 col-md-6">
            <div className="col-md-12">
              <div className="avatar-section">
                <img
                  src={ person.avatarUrl() ? person.avatarUrl() : avatarFallbackImage }
                  className="img-rounded avatar"
                  id="avatar-image"
                />
                <div className="username">
                  <h1>
                    <span id="heading-name">{ person.name() ? person.name()
                      : 'no name found' }</span>
                  </h1>
                  <span>{username}</span>
                  {this.isLocal() &&
                    <span>
                      &nbsp;|&nbsp;
                      <a onClick={ handleSignOut.bind(this) }>(Logout)</a>
                    </span>
                  }
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            {this.isLocal() &&
              <div className="new-status">
                <div className="col-md-12">
                  <textarea className="input-status" name="newStatus"
                    value={this.state.newStatus}
                    onChange={e => this.handleNewStatusChange(e)}
                    placeholder="What's on your mind?"
                  />

<input className="input-status" name="newTitle"

                    value={this.state.newTitle}
                    onChange={e => this.handleNewStatusChange(e)}
                    placeholder="your Title"
                  />

<input className="input-status" name="newEvent"

                    value={this.state.newEvent}
                    onChange={e => this.handleNewStatusChange(e)}
                    placeholder="Your Event Centre Name"
                  />


                </div>
                <div className="col-md-12 text-right">
                  <button
                    className="btn btn-primary btn-lg"
                    onClick={e => this.handleNewStatusSubmit(e)}
                  >
                    Submit
                  </button>
                </div>
              </div>
            }
            <div className="col-md-12 statuses">
            {this.state.isLoading && <span>Loading...</span>}
            {
              this.state.statuses.map((status) => (
                <Status
                  key={status.id}
                  status={status}
                  handleDelete={this.handleDelete}
                  isLocal={this.isLocal}
                />
              ))
            }
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div> : null
    );
  }
}
```

Here is just sample part for for **status.jsx** showing how I successfully return the status:

```
//some coding...
 return (
        <div className="status">
          <div className="status-text">
            {status.text}  
/*
{status.textTitle}  {status.textEvent}
*/
          </div>
        </div>
      )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the name attribute of the input field to your advantage.
And update your change handler function:

```
handleNewStatusChange(event) {
  this.setState({
    [event.target.name]: event.target.value,
  })
}
```

[more info on { [key]: value }](https://medium.com/@bretdoucette/understanding-this-setstate-name-value-a5ef7b4ea2b4)